# Soft Matzah for Ashkenazim

Tags: ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition, matzah

The Rama in 460:4 writes that one should make thin matzos and the Mishna Brurah 16 writes it should be thin. Rav Nebontzol (in his notes on the Mishna Brurah) points out the Be'er Heitiv 8 which writes the custom is to make it an etzbah thick, yet Rav Nebontzol writes further that such is not our custom; he adds that Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach held the custom of the Ashkenazim is to make the matzah as thin as possible.

Which Ashkenazic Poskim allow the soft* type of matzah for Pesach? Even though it may fit the requirement of the Rama, does one need a special mesorah to eat the this soft type of matza?

I know many people who would not eat it on Pesach, and certainly not for the mitzvah.

<sub>*Definition of the soft matzah: it is around a half inch thick and is soft.</sub>

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27356

Comment: My suspicion is that poskim who are medayik about gebruchts are going to forbid or at least frown on soft matzoh while those who are unconcerned with gebruchts are going to permit it.

Comment: @Tatpurusha I would guess that those poskim who think wearing the clothes that happened to be popular in Poland constitutes a minhag will also think that baking the matza the way they happened to do it in Poland would constitute a minhag.

Comment: Soft matzah for everyone! And kitniyos too...Really...

Comment: @Tatpurusha I've talked to a rov who doesn't personally eat gebrokts (although it's because of family minhag, not medayikdus) and who is lenient on soft matzah

Comment: I second that,I know of a great Posek Hador who eats gebrokts but doesn't allow eating the soft matzah

Comment: http://www.havabooks.co.il/smsSearch.asp?q=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA&page=1 R Aviner says it's Mutar

Comment: http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=160&ArticleID=8812 quotes R Nachum Rabinovich and R Shmuel Eliyahu as permitting

Comment: Off topic, but how do they do it? Do they make a thinner batter so that the heat can reach the inside? How do they knead it and roll it if it is all sticky?

Answer (score 9):

Rav Herschel Schachter wrote a Teshuvah several years ago that Ashkenazim may eat soft Matzah, which made some waves. There was controversy not from the Teshuvah, but from some individuals claiming that he was endorsing something specific, which he clarified later he was not doing. See [here](https://content.jwplatform.com/previews/teEFDlKn)* for a discussion of the issues, including his Teshuvah presented and explained a bit near the end, along with some other, related opinions about it.

Comment: also here: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2008/02/soft-matza.html

Comment: Does anyone know if the OU (for which RHS is a posek) does any Hashgacha on Matza?

Comment: @DoubleAA, hard or soft? There is hard Matzah bearing an OU, but I don't know if they are the original overseers or just provide their stamp to someone else's oversight.

Comment: the link from my post goes to http://softmatza.com/ where I asked Rabbi Ben Chaim if the person behind it is trustworthy.

Comment: @joshwaxman do you have a good permalink to R' Schachter's Teshuvah?

Comment: https://failedmessiah.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451b71f69e20147e38a6be0970b-800wi

Comment: https://jewishlink.news/features/30623-are-ashkenazic-jews-permitted-to-have-soft-matzah-on-pesach